# How to create an anonymous type like this var c = List<string, string[]>()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, generics, collections, anonymous-types

I would like to create a [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) that can be iterated, takes a string and a string array. The goal is to create a list of groups and each group contains persons:

I would like to know if something like this ***Pseudo-Code*** is possible:

```
var myAnoty =new List<string, string[]>();
myAnoty.add("Programmers", ["Linus", "Bill", "Anders"]);
myAnoty.add("Users", ["John", "Melissa", "Bert"]);
```

As [Muzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/933526/muzz) pointed out in the comments my pseudo code above is not using an Anonymous Type. Reed Copsey answer below is using them: `var m = new { Group = "Men", Members = new[] { "John", "Tom" } }`

### Working demo without using anonymous types

The following code [works in LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/CodeSnippetIDE.aspx):

```
void Main()
{
    List<Object> myAnoties = new List<Object>();
    myAnoties.Add(new Anoty {Group="Men",   Member=new string[]{"John","Tom"}} );
    myAnoties.Add(new Anoty {Group="Women", Member=new string[]{"Eve","Anna"}} );
    myAnoties.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
class Anoty{
    public string Group{get; set;}
    public string[] Member{get; set;}       
}
```

### Not working using anonymous types

The following code uses anonymous types. But somehow the string array will not work with anonymous types.

```
var m = new { Group= "Men", Member=string[]{"John","Tom"}};
var w = new { Group= "Women", Member=string[]{"Eve","Anna"}};
List<object> myAnoties = new List<object>();
myAnoties.Add(m);
myAnoties.Add(w);
```

Is there any way to get something like my Pseudo-Code `var x = new List<string,string[]>()` or something with anonymous types (like above) going?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to use anonymous types here?  Seems simpler to just make a type for holding this information.

Comment: have you tried `var foo = new List<String, dynamic>()`? (`dynamic` keyword)

Comment: I think you're getting anonymous types and type inference confused. Your pseudo code isn't using anonymous types.

Comment: @ReedCopsey i have many different types i would like to add - so using anonyous types would be nice so i do not have to care about creating types

Comment: @Muzz as far as i understand the documentation List<T> can only have one type. I tried this in LinqPad but it did not work: `var foo = new List<string, dynamic>();
 foo.add("Men", string[]{"John","Tom"});`

Comment: @Muzz You are right: the pseudo code is not using an anonymous type. 
But if i am not mistaken this line `var c = new { Group = "Men", Members = new[] { "John", "Tom" } }` is an anonymous type since no class is defined. My intention was to create a list of type T and T is not defined but anonymous: `var myAnoties = new List< new { Group= "Men", Member=string[]{"John","Tom"}}>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish something like your pseudo-code:

```
var myAnoty = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
myAnoty.Add("Programmers", new[] { "Linus", "Bill", "Anders" });
myAnoty.Add("Users", new[] { "John", "Melissa", "Bert" });
```

Or, if you want a `List<T>`:

```
var myAnoty = new List<Tuple<string, string[]>>();
myAnoty.Add(Tuple.Create("Programmers", new[] { "Linus", "Bill", "Anders" }));
myAnoty.Add(Tuple.Create("Users", new[] { "John", "Melissa", "Bert" }));
```

You can also use arrays within anonymous types:

```
var m = new { Group = "Men", Members = new[] { "John", "Tom" } } 
var w = new { Group = "Women", Members = new[] { "Eve", "Anna" } };
```

However, assigning this into a `List<object>` will make this effectively unusable, as you'll have no way to *access* the items by name anymore.  You could place them into a `List<dynamic>` and access them, however.

That being said, I'd strongly recommend reconsidering the goal of using anonymous typing entirely.  Using named types is typically preferential for situations where you're going to store the objects.  Anonymous types save a bit of typing in this scenario, but add a huge maintenance cost as they add a lot of complexities, and you lose a lot of safety (ie: not having proper constructors, etc).  The extra time required to create a custom type is typically far smaller  than the debugging and maintenance costs of using anonymous types over time in scenarios where you will persist the values.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers regarding maintenance cost. Your example with the string array helped a lot. I had tried `new string[]` and `string[]` but as i can see now `new[]` is the right way. 
Would you recommend using a Dictionary or to better create a type (struct or class like Anoty)?
Thanks

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree It depends on how this is being used - but in general, I prefer making a custom class.  That gives you the best of all worlds, at the cost of a little bit of extra typing up front.